# How to start autocomplete listener on page load Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Code below is Google Maps autocomplete search which only works on `place_changed` action.

Which event should I use to replace it and make it run on page load - based on value in `name="search"`?

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="Sport Caffe - Pool & Sports Bar, Bulevar Makedonski Prosvetiteli, Ohrid, North Macedonia" id="search_al" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">

<input type="hidden" name="place_id" value="" id="place_id_al">
<input type="hidden" name="icon" value="" id="icon_al">

<script>
var autocomplete_al = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_al);

autocomplete_al.setFields(['place_id', 'address_components']);

autocomplete_al.addListener('place_changed', function() {

  // on page load shows alert 1 and adds values based on `search` name
  alert(1);

  var place = autocomplete_al.getPlace();

  document.getElementById('place_id_al').value = place.place_id;
  document.getElementById('icon_al').value = place.icon;

});
</script>
```

Comment: If you already know the result address, you don't need autocomplete, just do a regular place search or use the Geocoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete is not the appropriate service to use if you already know the place. This is why [place_changed](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#Autocomplete.place_changed) is the single event used here; a user selects a place from a list of Autocomplete predictions based on what the user types into the input field. Like in [these](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) [examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform).

Therefore I recommend you use a Place Search service such as [Find Place from Query](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#find_place_from_query). You can make the query right away using the `callback` parameter to initialize the Places service. See Google's code example below:

```
<script>
  var map;
  var service;
  var infowindow;

  function initMap() {
    var sydney = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.867, 151.195);

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'), {center: sydney, zoom: 15});

    var request = {
      query: 'Museum of Contemporary Art Australia',
      fields: ['name', 'geometry'],
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, function(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          createMarker(results[i]);
        }

        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
    });
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Hope this helps!